# PDO connection to DB2 server with system dsn and odbc

Tags: sql, dns, db2, odbc, connection-string

I can connect to iseries DB2 database with this connection string;

```
$server="systemdnsfile1"; #the name of the iSeries
$user="user"; #a valid username that will connect to the DB
$pass="pass"; #a password for the username
$conn=odbc_connect($server,$user,$pass); #you may have to remove quotes
```

I want to connect with PDO but I could not find correct code
this is  working code for mysql, how can I convert it to system dns type ?

```
@n$db = @new PDO(
            "mysql:host={$sql_details['host']};dbname={$sql_details['db']}",
            $sql_details['user'],
            $sql_details['pass'],
            array( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION )
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
$user= ...;
$password=...;

try {
  $connection = new PDO("ibm:YOUR_DSN_NAME", $user, $password, array(
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION)
  );
}
catch (Exception $e) {
  echo($e->getMessage());
}
```

Comment: thank you tried but get error ; {"error":"An error occurred while connecting to the database. The error reported by the server was: could not find driver"}

Comment: tried this one $db = new PDO("odbc:DRIVER={iSeries Access ODBC DRIVER}; ", 
    "SYSTEM={my_dsn_name}; ", 
    "UID={user}; ", 
    "PWD={pass}",
 array( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION ));  error Warning: PDO::__construct() expects at most 4 parameters, 5 given in .......... and Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on null in

Comment: Edit your question to give the PDO_IBM version detail, the PHP version,  your operating-system, and the ODBC driver detail (which client type and version).